# dynamically add footer or header in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

i want to add footer dynamically in my jquery mobile page..

```
<div data-role="page" id="homePage" data-theme="b" data-add-back-btn="true">  
  <div data-role="header"><h3></h3></div>
  <div data-role="content">
  <ul data-role="listview" id="aaa">

   </ul>
   </div>
```

the i tried to add footer dynamically..

```
 $('#homePage').append('<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"><i>Copyright  &copy; 2013</i></div>').trigger( "create" );
```

but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: It's working as expected. what was the notice. can u be specific?

Comment: `$('#header id').trigger('pagecreate')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Akki619/FVh2R/)

```
 $('#homePage').append('<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"><i>Copyright  &copy; 2013</i></div>').trigger( "pagecreate" );
```

I have used the same code from the template of jquery website. CSS needs to be managed for this.

**EDIT as pointed in below comment:**

[**Fiddle1**](http://jsfiddle.net/Akki619/FVh2R/2/)

Comment: Your answer is not clear. You're repeating code from the question but the markup is not the same (e.g. the `data-position="fixed"` attribute was lost along the way). You're not triggering the event necessary for jQuery Mobile to enhance the new markup (`pagecreate`, as Omar points out in his comment). Your fiddle does not show much (it doesn't even reference jQuery Mobile), and your last sentence (`CSS needs to be managed for this`) is very vague.

Comment: Apologize, I have putted wrong fiddle. Thanks for pointing out. CSS needs to be managed was supported by my fiddle in the context but I guess I posted wrong fiddle. Anyways...thanks

Comment: Explain why `pagecreate` worked while `create` didn't. Posting an answer with explanation doesn't help.